# Cant get to work MagicSuggest.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, magicsuggest

I don't know what I'm missing, but I can't get to work MagicSuggest, can someone help me out? I have the following code:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Portal</title>
    <link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
    <link href="assets/magicsuggest/magicsuggest.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div id="#ms" class="form-control"></div>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/magicsuggest/magicsuggest.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#ms').magicSuggest({
        data: [{'id':'0', 'name':'Paris'}, {'id':'1', 'name':'New York'}],
        valueField: 'id',
        displayField: 'name'
    });
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

I already have the files in the correct folder location and the web server is includint it in the sources.

Please help.

Comment: Your div ID shouldn't have a pound sign in the HTML markup.  It should be `<div id="ms" class="form-control"></div>`.  It's okay that you're referencing it with a pound sign in your JS.  That said, you don't tell us what's not working, so it's hard to diagnose your issue(s).

Comment: thank you that was my mistake!!! sorry i didnt realized that, what a doom mistake i should go sleep.        That made it work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your div ID shouldn't have a pound sign in the HTML markup. It should be:

```
<div id="ms" class="form-control"></div>
```

*(Added as a answer instead in addition to a comment)*

Comment: Thanks, also i think the documentation should not have that tag, look at: http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/doc.html and the autor use the div with the # sign <div id="#magicsuggest"></div> Thats was my problem.

Comment: Ugh my bad sorry for that! I just fixed the doc. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you have missed that HTML div with id="ms" as shown as above by Mr.Marc

`<div id="ms" class="form-control"></div>`

put that in your html page under `<body>`tag.
i hope you have gone through this following link.

http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/tutorial-3.php